# Does XmlPrime support .net core?

Tags: .net-core, xml-validation, schematron

While porting a solution from .net framework 4.6 to .net core. I am stuck with  xml validation using schematron part and I am using xmlPrime for that, Seems like xmlprime does not support .net core.
Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple examples adapted from https://github.com/XmlPrime/Examples/tree/master/Query and https://github.com/XmlPrime/Examples/tree/master/Transform then run fine to execute XQuery 3 and XSLT 2 in the .NET Core 3 app.

Check from here [Are there any XSLT and XQuery Processors available for .NET Core 3.0 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926380/are-there-any-xslt-and-xquery-processors-available-for-net-core-3-0-apps)